# Appointment Send and Send Update

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

How can I know if for any appointment "Send" was clicked or " Send Update" or "Send Cancellation" was clicked.I have `Application_ItemSend` event which fires for both Send,Send Update and Send Cancellation. One way would be add a custom property and set some value when the appointment is initially created. But I don't seem to find a way to differentiate the button click. Is adding custom property the only way or is there any built in property which I can use. Appointment item I am assigning as below.

```
var appointment = Globals.MedearcOutlook2010AddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the **MAPI property** [`PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb159898.aspx) to see whether the appointment has been sent yet (`isUpdate=false`) or it is an update to an existing appointment (`isUpdate=true`). I didn't see a [native property member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_members.aspx) for doing this.

```cs
string PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040";
bool isUpdate = false;
try
{
    DateTime message_delivery = appointment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME);
    isUpdate = true; // if it makes it here then the message has been delivered
}
catch { }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution seems not to solve the problem stated by San. In some tests it seems that this value does not represent the time when the item was "sent", in a manner how outlook interprets sending appointments, but the time when the client has sent a message to the server containing information about the appointment. So it is enough to save the appointment rather than "send" it (possibly to other participants).